# How to create azure container registry with yaml template?

Tags: php, azure, azure-devops, devops

I have a php application

And I am bussy with a pipeline for creating a azure container registry and building and pushing a image to the azure container registry. So this is the part of building an pushing a image to the azure container registry:

```
# Docker
# Build and push an image to Azure Container Registry
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/docker

trigger:
- master

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'hackaton_internetsuite_connection'
  imageRepository: 'internetsuite-webscraper'
  containerRegistry: 'internetsuite.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePath: '**/Dockerfile'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)
```

and this is the template for creating the registry container:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "registryName": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "registryLocation": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "registrySku": {
            "defaultValue": "Standard",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries",
            "sku": {
                "name": "[parameters('registrySku')]"
            },
            "name": "[parameters('registryName')]",
            "apiVersion": "2017-10-01",
            "location": "[parameters('registryLocation')]",
            "properties": {
                "adminUserEnabled": "true"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But now I want to include the code in the yaml file for building the azure container registry.

So what I have to include in the yaml file so that a azure container registry will be build?

I have it now like this:

```
# Docker
# Build and push an image to Azure Container Registry
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/docker

trigger:
- master

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'hackaton_internetsuite_connection'
  imageRepository: 'internetsuite-webscraper'
  acrHostName: 'internetsuite.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePath: '**/Dockerfile'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)

     # Build container image
    - task: Docker@1
      displayName: 'Build container image'
      inputs:
        azureSubscriptionEndpoint: 'hackaton_internetsuite_connection'
        azureContainerRegistry: '$(acrHostName)'
        imageName: '$(imageName):$(Build.BuildId)'
        useDefaultContext: false
        buildContext: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/PublishedWebApp'

    # Push container image
    - task: Docker@1
      displayName: 'Push container image'
      inputs:
        azureSubscriptionEndpoint: 'hackaton_internetsuite_connection'
        azureContainerRegistry: '$(acrHostName)'
        command: 'Push an image'
        imageName: '$(imageName):$(Build.BuildId)'
```

and the name of my service connection is: hackaton_internetsuite_connection

But then I get this error:

```
The pipeline is not valid. Job Build: Step Docker2 input azureSubscriptionEndpoint expects a service connection of type AzureRM but the provided service connection hackaton_internetsuite_connection is of type dockerregistry. Job Build: Step Docker3 input azureSubscriptionEndpoint expects a service connection of type AzureRM but the provided service connection hackaton_internetsuite_connection is of type dockerregistry.
```

Comment: You should use the `task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3` in order to apply your template on azure using a service connection that you will create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the template sample, this is an ARM template.

In your YAML sample, the docker task is used to deploy the Docker image to existing Azure Container Registry. It will not create a new Azure Container Registry.

To deploy the ARM template, you need to use the task:[Azure Resource Group Deployment task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=azure-devops)

For example:

```
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  displayName: 'ARM Template deployment: Resource Group scope'
  inputs:
    azureResourceManagerConnection: serviceconnection
    subscriptionId: xx
    resourceGroupName: xx
    location: xx
    csmFile: templatefile(template.json)
    csmParametersFile: paramtersfile(paramters.json)
```

For the service connection, you need to use the **Azure Resource Manager** type  service connection.

For example:

[image]

In your case, the service connect：hackaton_internetsuite_connection is a Docker Registry service connection. This is also why you see the error in the pipeline. azureSubscriptionEndpoint field needs to input Azure Resource Manager type service connection.